# Validator validates when it should not in JSF

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a form that needs validate a `<p:inputText>` only when a specific value is selected in a `<p:selectOneMenu>`. Let's supose the `<p:selectOneMenu>` have 3 values:

```
'VALUE NORMAL'
'NEEDS VALIDATION'
'OTHER VALUE'
```

When user selects 'NEEDS VALIDATION' the validator should verify the length of the input, and when user selects any other value the validator should not verify the length of the input.

I'm using `<f:validateLength>` this way:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{model.selected}"
                 required="#{param['REQUIRED']}"
                 onchange="controladorSelecaoManifestacaoDestinatario.atualizarCampo(this);">

    <f:selectItems value="#{tipoEventoNfeEnum.values()}"
                   var="tipo"
                   itemValue="#{tipo}"
                   itemLabel="#{tipo.descricao}" />

    <p:ajax event="change"
            process="@this"
            update="justificativa"
            global="false"
            immediate="true"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:inputText id="justificativa"
             value="#{model.someText}"
             required="#{param['REQUIRED'] and model.selected == 'NEEDS VALIDATION'}"
             disabled="#{model.selected != 'NEEDS VALIDATION'}">

    <f:validateLength minimum="15" maximum="255" for="justificativa"/>
</p:inputText>
```

If I open the form and select 'VALUE NORMAL' or 'OTHER VALUE' and submit the form, it correctly DOES NOT check the length.

If I open the form and select 'NEEDS VALIDATION' and submit the form, it correctly CHECK the length.

However If I open the form and select 'NEEDS VALIDATION' and submit the form, and then select 'VALUE NORMAL' or 'OTHER VALUE' it still check for validation. Is there a way I can solve it?

Comment: Is this in a dialog, or what do you mean by "open the form"? If yes, try to put a <p:resetInput target="..."/> on the button that shows the dialog

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar it is not a popup, it is a simple pane.